# Основная мысль данного текста

Tags: текст

Какова основная мысль данного текста?
"Не то важно, что Анна умерла от родов, а то, что все эти Анны, Мавры, Пелагеи
с раннего утра до потёмок гнут спины, болеют от непосильного труда, всю жизнь
дрожат за голодных и больных детей, всю жизнь боятся смерти и болезней, всю
жизнь лечатся, рано блёкнут, рано старятся и умирают в грязи и в вони; их дети,
подрастая, начинают ту же музыку, и так проходят сотни лет, и миллиарды
людей живут хуже животных — только ради куска хлеба, испытывая постоянный
страх. Весь ужас их положения в том, что им некогда о душе подумать, некогда
вспомнить о своём образе и подобии; голод, холод, животный страх, масса
труда, точно снеговые обвалы, загородили им все пути к духовной
деятельности, именно к тому самому, что отличает человека от животного и
составляет единственное, ради чего стоит жить. Вы приходите к ним на помощь
с больницами и школами, но этим не освобождаете их от пут, а, напротив, ещё
больше порабощаете, так как, внося в их жизнь новые предрассудки, вы
увеличиваете число их потребностей, не говоря уже о том, что за книжки они
должны платить земству и, значит, сильнее гнуть спин"

---

Варианты ответов:

***1) Счастье для русского человека недоступно, он упивается страданием.

2) Жизнь в тревогах и заботах не позволяет быть человеку счастливым.

3) Народ много и тяжело работает.

4) Сначала нужно обеспечивать народ жизненно необходимым, а потом заботиться о душе.***

Answer (score 1):

Я за № 2 (Жизнь в тревогах и заботах не позволяет человеку быть счастливым).